# How to call a comboBox from another form (class) to be used inside a button

Tags: c#, forms

I want to call a some combo-box items so i can make an if /else statements and output a form.The combo-box items are out side of my class(Form) how can i access them i tried this(below) but the error says does not exist in the current context.I also changed it
the method from private to public

```
public void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if(comboBoxD.Text == "Alphabet" && comboBoxType.Text == "Numbers")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to share `comboBox` control among classes.

Comment: @Hassan Nisar How do i find them and go about it may i please have an example

Comment: Can you add more code in your question. How you open new form?

Answer (score 1):

Send `ComboBox` from form1 to form2 using constructor. Here is example:

Form1 Class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
   public Form1()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form2 f2 = new Form2(comboBox1, comboBox2);
       f2.Show();
   }
}
```

Form2 Class:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{ 
   ComboBox comboBoxD; 
   ComboBox comboBoxType;

   public Form2(ComboBox cb, ComboBox cbType)
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBoxD = cb;
        comboBoxType = cbType;
   }

   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   protected void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {           
        if(comboBoxD.Text == "Alphabet" && comboBoxType.Text == "Numbers")
        {

        }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Here is another approach for accessing controls present in another form.

Default `Modifiers` of every control is `private`. For controls you want to access from another form you have change `Modifiers` property as `Public`.

[image]

**Form1** Class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
   public Form1()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
       f2.Show();
   }
}
```

**Form2** Class:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 f1;
    public Form2(Form1 f)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      f1 = f;
    }

    protected void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if(f1.comboBoxD.Text == "Alphabet" && f1.comboBoxType.Text == "Numbers")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works however can i use this for  a radioButton as well?example  ` if (comboBoxD.Text == "Alphabet" && comboBoxType.Text == "Numbers" && radioButtonBook == "TextBook"){ etc};

Comment: Yes you can add number of controls. But if you want to share number of control then you can send `Form1` object as well.

Comment: May i please have an example

Comment: Yes. I have updated answer. For every control present in `Form1` which needs to be accessed in `Form2`. You have to change `Modifier` as `Public`

Comment: Oh so the reason for the F is to allow us to use Form1 and form1 as many times?

Comment: `f` is the same instance of the `Form1` which was created. Here we are passing same instance of `Form1` to `Form2`. So when `Form2` constructor is called `f1` gets the value that is same instance of `Form1`. Hence we are able to access all controls within `Form1` which are declared as `Public` using Modifiers property.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `public` method in your `ComboBox`'s class and then call it from where you have instance of that form.

like this:

in your main form:

```
  using (var modal = new MyModal())
  {
            modal.ShowDialog();
            modal.getSomething();
  }
```

in your modal:

```
  public string getSomething()
  {
       return yourComboBox.Text;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ComboBox is only available in the codebehind file of your Form.

One solution would be to store a reference to your combobox as a property in your codebehind.

like this:

```
public ComboBox myCmbBox { get; private set; }
```

and access it in the codebehind of form2.